# How to create cancellable service in android?

Tags: android, notifications, android-service

I need to do some work in background and it should be cancellable (I mean that user should be able to things:
1. Stop the service.
2. Undo all the work that service have done.

I probably extend service and use thread to do the work doing something like that

```
while(!cancelled) {
   doWork();
}
```

In thread run method. But I think that someone should already done that.

Also how to stop service from the notification?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html Should get you started

Comment: I've read it already. Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't see anything about how to cancel service from notification or how to cancel work that service is doing.

Comment: To cancel a service, use the `stopSelf()` method of the service class.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf()

Comment: Yeah, ok. How to interrupt service from notification? I can not call stopSelf() from notification, right? I need to pass intent or something? If so, then I can't use IntentService which I'm using now for example.

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you say, "From notification"?  Your service is a separate class, and you can get messages to it by broadcasting intents, or by using messages and the Handler class (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).  This service should give you an idea of how to do it with intents https://gist.github.com/nathansizemore/ef43a545ab9a2fa13ae5